# Linq grouping with child condition

Tags: c#, linq, distinct, grouping

I have ORM data type like below

```
public class PackData
{
   public int PackId
   public int ClientId
   public DateTime DateCreated
   public List<PackItemData> PackItems
}

public class PackItemData
{
   public int PackId
   public string DeviceId
}
```

I can query PackData and PackItemData with Linq

```
var data = DataTable.Where(pack =>  pack.DateCreated >= startDate 
                                    && pack.DateCreated <= endDate)
```

I want to group/distinct child data (PackItemData) to get unique result for device Id

How can I achieve that?

Comment: it might be helpful if you show a sample input and expected output

Comment: can you be more specific??

Comment: are you trying to group PackData by deviceId??

Comment: I expected output, List<PackData> that all List<PackItem> already distinct for all, so I have device Id unique for all List<PackData> thats mean, List<PackData> only have one for specific deviceId

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `SelectMany`. This will flatten out your `List<List<PackItemData>>` to `List<PackItemData>`

```
var data=DataTable.Where(pack =>  pack.DateCreated >= startDate 
                                  && pack.DateCreated <= endDate)
                   .SelectMany(i => i.PackItems)
                   .GroupBy(i => i.DeviceId).Select(i => i.First());
```

Comment: But what will be the output of this query?? He wanted to group items ryt?? This query will provide only the distinct deviceids..

Comment: This query give me a PackItems result data, how can I get PackData list result that pack items already distinct by device Id for all pack datas?

Answer (score 0):

```
var groups = DataTable
    .Where(pack => pack.DateCreated >= startDate && pack.DateCreated <= endDate)
    .SelectMany(pack => pack.PackItems)
    .GroupBy(item => item.DeviceId);
```

You might want to start with `SelectMany` which will allow you to enumerate over all of the PackItems in all of the PackDatas. This gives you an `IEnumerable<PackItemData>` which you can then use in your grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Linq [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and Distinct methods should get you what you need.

```
var data=DataTable.Where(pack => pack.DateCreated >= startDate && pack.DateCreated <= endDate)
                  .Select( pack => pack.PackItems)
                  .GroupBy( p => p.PackId, p => p.DeviceId, (key, p) => new PackItemData { PackId = key, DeviceId = p});
```

I'm not 100% this works, as I have yet to run a test, but this should get you close to where you're going.

Source: [Group by in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)

Comment: Use SelectMany Instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var data = DataTable.Where(pack =>  pack.DateCreated >= startDate 
                              && pack.DateCreated <= endDate).SelectMany(s=> s.PackItems).GroupBy(p => p.DeviceId).Select(r=> r);
```

I think this should work.

Comment: This query give me a PackItems result data, how can I get PackData list result that pack items already distinct by device Id for all pack datas